# Outer Join in mYsql Qyery

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have folowing MYsql Query And Trying to right outer join but unable to understan how to do this

here is query plase any one help

```
select lp_des.lpname,today.cnt_veh_tdy,todate.cnt_veh_tdate
from
(select distinct registration.lpcode,loadingpoint.lpname 
from registration,loadingpoint
where registration.lpcode=loadingpoint.lpcode) lp_des,
(select lpcode,count(vehicleno) cnt_veh_tdate
from registration
where registration.companycode='01'
group by lpcode) todate,
(
select lpcode,count(vehicleno) cnt_veh_tdy
from registration
where registration.companycode='01'
and registration.date=(select max(date) from registration)
group by lpcode) today
right outer join today on lp_des.lpcode = today.lpcode
right outer join todate on lp_des.lpcode = todate.lpcode
```

I want to make right outer join on this part

```
where lp_des.lpcode=todate.lpcode
and   lp_des.lpcode=today.lpcode
```

Please help and Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have to be a `right outer join`? Maybe you should describe what is the result you want, instead of posting only the solution you think you need.

Comment: Also, about the whole world uses `left join` (=`left outer join`). Every right join on A and B can be rewritten to a left join B and A, which makes it more readable. Especially mixing right joins and left joins in one query makes it harder to read, test and modify.

Comment: I have made right outer join in above query please now chek what may be syntax error in query

Comment: Was it really easier to post that whole chunk of code here instead of just checking the manual on `right join`?

Comment: I am using Query and Subquery too thats i show up my whole query so it will easy to undertand i still not got my answer please change my query to actual outer join

Comment: Do you understand what I'm saying? At all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for this:

```
select 
  lp_des.lpname,
  today.cnt_veh_tdy,
  todate.cnt_veh_tdate
from
  (select distinct 
    r.lpcode,
    l.lpname 
  from 
    registration r
    inner join loadingpoint l on l.lpcode = r.lpcode) lp_des
  right join
    (select 
      r.lpcode,
      count(r.vehicleno) cnt_veh_tdate
    from 
      registration r
    where 
      r.companycode='01'
    group by 
      lpcode) todate on todate.lpcode = lp_des.lpcode
  right join
    (select 
      r.lpcode,
      count(r.vehicleno) cnt_veh_tdy
    from 
      registration r
    where 
      r.companycode = '01'
      and registration.date = (select max(date) from registration)
    group by 
      r.lpcode) today on today.lpcode = lp_des.lpcode
```

But I think you mean this:

```
select
  r.lpcode,
  l.lpname,
  count(r.vehicleno) cnt_veh_tdate,
  count(case when r.date = md.date then r.vehicleno else null end) cnt_veh_tdy
from
  registration r
  inner join (select max(rm.date) maxdate from registration rm) md
  left join loadingpoint l on l.lpcode = r.lpcode
where
  r.companycode = '01'
group by 
  r.lpcode
```

and maybe even this:

```
select
  r.lpcode,
  l.lpname,
  count(r.vehicleno) cnt_veh_tdate,
  count(case when r.date = date() then r.vehicleno else null end) cnt_veh_tdy
from
  registration r
  left join loadingpoint l on l.lpcode = r.lpcode
where
  r.companycode = '01'
group by 
  r.lpcode
```

If I read it correctly, you want a query that returns the number of vehicles for company 1 assigned to a loading point, overall as well as for today only. And you also want that count for vehicles that do not have loading point assigned yet. 
Though it would help if *you* would have added this description. It will help the ones answering your question, but it will also help you writing the right query in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a right outer join is:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM t1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field2
```

If you're joining on the same field you can use `USING` instead of `ON`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM t1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 USING (field)
```

Comment: Kindly chek my query and make outer join in that query ur example is not working